# Android Studio "Create New Class" strange UI window

Tags: android, android-studio

I see the following UI when creating a new Java class. I can recall I had the *normal* one and I see the *normal* one in video tutorials.

My "create new class" window:

[image]

The one I would prefer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this dialog by reset your class template to default in Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates:
[image]

This dialog shown when template has variables which can not be provided automatically. I think studio installer forgot update templates from previous setup where new class dialog had more options.